# Both centering and left alignment in same column in S colummn from siunitx

Tags: vertical-alignment, siunitx

Here we go again with an `S` column problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\kroner}{kr.}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{Priser på får og uldmængden, de giver.}
 \label{tbl:1}
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-text-alignment=left]
    S[table-format=4.0]
    S[table-format=1.0]
  }
   \toprule
    {Fårerace}     & {Vejledende pris per får} & {Uldmængde per får om året} \\
    {---}          & {\si{\kroner}}            & {\si{\kg}}                  \\
   \midrule
    {Dorset}       & 1650                    & 4                         \\
    {Gotland}      & 1595                    & 5                         \\
    {Marsk}        & 1525                    & 7                         \\
    {Rygja}        & 1800                    & 6                         \\
    {Texel}        & 1725                    & 5                         \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like `Fårerace` and `---` to be centered in the first column instead of left-aligned as the rest of the entries. How do I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `S` column type is not necessary here because there are no numbers to be aligned. A simple `l` column with the content in the head centered by `\multicolumn` will do.

```
\documentclass[11pt,danish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  ae={æ},
  oslash={ø}
}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\kroner}{kr.}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Priser på får og uldmængden, de giver.}
    \label{tbl:1}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-format=4.0]
      S[table-format=1.0]
    }\toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Fårerace}     & {Vejledende pris per får} & {Uldmængde per får om året} \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{---}          & {\si{\kroner}}            & {\si{\kg}}                  \\ \midrule
      {Dorset}       & 1650                    & 4                         \\
      {Gotland}      & 1595                    & 5                         \\
      {Marsk}        & 1525                    & 7                         \\
      {Rygja}        & 1800                    & 6                         \\
      {Texel}        & 1725                    & 5                         \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]